# Getting an exception Incorrect syntax near ','. in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

I am getting getting an error in C# where I am using int, date, float, varchar datatype

following the command

```
con.Open();
string cb = "insert into tran1(tno,billno,Tdate,Acno,SubTotal,TaxPer,Discountper,DiscountAmt,TaxAmount,GrandTotal,UserId,Remarks,cash,change)values(" + txtTno.Text + ",'" + txtBillNo.Text + "',"+dtpBillDate.Text+","+txtACNO.Text+","+txtSubTotal.Text+","+txtTaxPer.Text+","+txtDiscountPer.Text+","+txtDiscountAmount.Text+","+txtTaxAmt.Text+","+txtTotal.Text+","+txtUserId.Text+",'"+txtNarr.Text+"',"+txtCash.Text+",'"+txtChange.Text+"')";
cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert a row into a database. Try the SQL manually in a local database. There's a strong chance that it's either a problem with syntax or a mismatch in number of columns versus number of values.

Comment: For your current problem and to prevent many many more errors use [SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please start to execute SQL Queries with Parameters. This will not only protect you from SQL njections but also makes it easier with different data types, sinces it converts it to the needed. [See this MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Obligatory warning: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: the most possible place causing the error in the query is at this `dtpBillDate.Text`, of course using SqlParamaters is a must-do.

Comment: A likely explanation could be, that one of you textboxes is left empty, and hence causes two commas in a row. But as the others say, use parameterization.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes round your parameters in your SQL Statement...
For example;

```
values (" + txtTno.Text + ",
```

will just do

```
values ( Whatever ,
```

which should be

```
values ('" + txtTno.Text + "',
```

to give the correct;

```
values ('Whatever',
```

However as others have said in comments **DO NOT DO IT THIS WAY** - Instead use SQL Parameters, as this is both less error prone, more readible, and saves you from nasty things like SQL Injection.

This would look like;

```
values ( @txtTno ,
```

Then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtTno", txtTno.Text);
```

Comment: the quote can be missed if the text value is castable to number (and really treated as numeric data), so I guess just `dtpBillDate.Text` should be quoted (and some others have already been quoted by himself).

Comment: To add on to this answer, look into the using statement. It will release your unmanaged resources for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is you are concatenating values that should have `'` ticks around them like `Date`s. You can fix this by using parameters but I recommend all of the following:

1. If you are doing a non-query operation like `INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE` then use `ExecuteNonQuery`, **not** `ExecuteReader` which is meant for reading results back from a query.
2. **Always use parameters** instead of string concatenation in your queries. It guards against sql injection and ensures you never has issues with strings that contain escape charaters.

   - Parameters are value place holders
   - When you add the value of the parameter it should match the type in your schema, so use System.DateTime for Dates, `int` for `int`, `string` for `varchar`/`nvarchar` etc.
   - Always specify the `SqlDbType`
   - If applicable specify the length as well
3. Try not to reuse connections unless you have to. The main reason is that you generally want to close connections as soon as possible and it will guard you against possible race conditions later if you have multiple events/actions that can occur at the same time that are data driven.
4. Close your connections as soon as possible so you do not have open external resources.
5. To ensure that 1 and 2 occur wrap your `IDisposable` types in a `using` block.
6. Add your connection string to the `app.config` or `web.config` and retrieve it using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name-here"].ConnectionString` (*requires a reference to assembly `System.configuration`*)

Code

```
var query = "INSERT INTO tran1(tno, billno, Tdate, Acno, SubTotal, TaxPer, Discountper, DiscountAmt, TaxAmount, GrandTotal, UserId, Remarks, cash, change) VALUES(@tno, @billno, @Tdate, @Acno, @SubTotal, @TaxPer, @Discountper, @DiscountAmt, @TaxAmount, @GrandTotal, @UserId, @Remarks, @cash, @change)";

using(var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con))
{
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tno", SqlDbType.Int){Value = int.Parse(txtTno.Text)});
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@billno", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100){Value = txtBillNo.Text});
  // convert your string date into a DateTime, use Parse or ParseExact with the appropriate formater and CultureInfo if applicable
  command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Tdate", SqlDbType.Date){Value = DateTime.Parse(dtpBillDate.Text)});

  // continue to add the rest of your parameters here


  con.Open();
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: its showing another error that is

Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId".

Comment: The code above is not complete, you have to add all of the parameters for it to work. See the comment `continue to add the rest of your parameters here`. The error `Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId"` means you did not add parameter `@UserId` to the parameter list.

Comment: its done sir .... actually problem was UserId is passing blank in this windows form data base ..... i want to auto pass that user id from which the software is logged in.... then i want to know how to add userid of logged in user in windows form application.